# PHP : Space displayed instead of line break after concatenation

Tags: php

I'm just starting in php (and on stackoverfow) and I was using some code founded on php.net's manual to do some tests. I tried to edit a line to add a \n.

```
echo gettype($a_bool)."\n";
echo gettype($a_str);
```

Those 2 lines are supposed to display

```
boolean
string
```

on my page but instead I get:

```
boolean string
```

I'd like to know if the problem is coming from my use of \n or concatenate or from somewhere else.
Edit : I'm adding my code that I'm executing on mozilla with a local server using apache.

```
<?php
$a_bool = TRUE;   // un booléen
$a_str  = "foo";  // une chaîne de caractères
$a_str2 = 'foo';  // une chaîne de caractères
$an_int = 12;     // un entier

echo gettype($a_bool)."\br";
echo gettype($a_str);

// Si c'est un entier, incrément de 4
if (is_int($an_int)) {
    $an_int += 4;
    }

// Si $a_bool est une chaîne de caractères, on l'affiche
if (is_string($a_bool)) {
    echo "String: $a_bool";
}
?>
```

I changed my "\n" for a "\br" as recomended and this is what's displayed on my page now :

```
boolean\brstring
```

Just fixed it with 
 (I was just not using it correctly).
Thank you.

Comment: *on my page but instead I get* If you are talking about an HTML page you have to use the `<br>` tag not `\n`

Comment: I recommend to learn html basics first and than start with php, if you want to use php to generate html output.

Comment: I'm starting from nothing (just did some C, C#, C++ and python for basic uses), got some base in HTML to start but I think I may have to get further into this. Anyway, thanks for your help;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Content Type of PHP is `text/html`.

To create the desired result, you have to change the Content Type to `text/plain` by adding this at the first line:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Also, try not to use `\n`, use `PHP_EOL` constant instead, i.e.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo gettype($a_bool) . PHP_EOL;
echo gettype($a_str) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are to run the script on the commandline, then use

```
echo gettype($a_bool)."\n";
echo gettype($a_str);
```

However if you are to view the result in a web browser like Chrome or Firefox or Internet Explorer , then use

```
echo gettype($a_bool)."\br";
echo gettype($a_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by @Jens:

```
$a_bool = true;
$a_str = "string";
echo gettype($a_bool)."<br>";
echo gettype($a_str);
```

Comment: Just fixed it, I did not use <br> correctly, thanks.

Comment: Nope, that's bad. In order to have valid HTML, you should at least adding HTML structure, or convert the Content Type to plain text.